# 1:1: Umbrella header for module 'AudioKit' does not include header 'AK4ParamRampBase.hpp'

Tags: audiokit

I get the following warning when building AudioKit.

> :1:1: Umbrella header for module 'AudioKit' does not
>   include header 'AK4ParamRampBase.hpp'

and

> :1:1: Umbrella header for module 'AudioKit' does not
>   include header 'AK4LinearParamRamp.hpp

'

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask a good question

Answer (score 2):

In the current develop branch of AudioKit, there are no compilation warnings so this will be gone in the next release. In the meantime, its just a warning so you can safely ignore it.